# UML syntax highlighting for Sublime

Tags: colors, uml, editor, sublimetext, syntax-highlighting

I cannot find the **syntax** for UML in the bottom right **syntax** list. I am guessing UML is not a standard language

Can anyone help me out? (It is quite a nightmare to code in plain text!)

Thanks a lot,

M

Comment: UML is a _visual_ modelling language, how come you're using Sublime for this? Shouldn't you be using a _visual_ editor, instead of a text editor?

Comment: Having said that, I don't think Sublime has any support whatsoever for "drawing" UML, how would that be possible, maybe as ASCII art? I really think you should use a different tool ;)

Comment: Did you by any chance mean XML rather than UML??

Comment: I am basically looking for a support for syntax highlighting of PlantUML files. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Simple Steps to install the syntax plugin for UML

1. Download this plugin package for Sublime - [Diagram plugin
   Git](https://github.com/jvantuyl/sublime_diagram_plugin). as TAR ball
2. UnZip and save it to your package folder. In MacOS, copy the folder to `~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/User/`
3. Restart your sublime
4. Open Command Pallete under Tools ->
   Command Pallete or CMD + Shift + P  Type 'Diagram' and chose.
5. You
   are "All Set"

**P.S. -** 
 Install it on `~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/User/` Location on your MacOS.